# Pasar datos a un jDialog desde una BD

Tags: java, java-swing, ms-access

Hola buenas noches quiero pasar datos desde mi BD a un JDialog como se ve paso el código y la pregunta que están en la tabla pero no se como pasar los valores de los combos y de las opciones al jDialog de antemano muchas gracias.

```
private void btnEditarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          

    int row = TablaPreguntas.getSelectedRow();
    if (row != -1) {
        try {
            codigo = Integer.parseInt(TablaPreguntas.getValueAt(row, 0).toString());
            this.txtAreaPregunta.setText(this.TablaPreguntas.getValueAt(row, 1).toString());           
            this.cboEspecialidad.setSelectedItem(ps.getEspecialidad());
            this.txtRespuestaA.setText(ps.getOpcionA());
            //this.txtRespuestaB.setText(ps.getOpcionA());
            //this.txtRespuestaC.setText(ps.getOpcionA());
            //this.txtRespuestaD.setText(ps.getOpcionA());
            //this.txtRespuestaE.setText(ps.getOpcionA());
            //this.cboRespuesta.setSelectedItem(ps.getRespuesta());
            DialogPregunta.setSize(672, 539);
            DialogPregunta.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            DialogPregunta.setVisible(true);
            nuevo++;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "No ha seleccionado ninguna fila");
    }
```

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con "pasar los valores de los combos y de las opciones al JDialog"? ¿Quieres que el diálogo te muestre combos y otros campos? ¿O solo componer un mensaje con esos valores? ¿Cuál es el tipo de `DialogoPregunta`? NOTA: Nombre de métodos y variables siempre empiezan por minúscula.

Comment: Lo que pasa es que en un jframe tengo una tabla que tiene(codigo y nombre), quiero hacer la función modificar y para ello quiero pasar los datos a campos de texto ya pasé el código y el nombre de la tabla automáticamente pero quiero que tambien aparezcan otros valores que no están en esa tabla como puede ser apellido, telefono que no están en la tabla pero si en la base de datos